# I sent the post type fetch to this form but I received undefined on the server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I sent the post type fetch to this form but I received undefined on the server side

this is my fetch:

```
const { text, id } = Data;
fetch('http://localhost:3001/add'
      , {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({ text, id })

      }
    ).then(res => console.log(res))
```

and this is my server

```
const Data=[{name:'amir',id:1,messeges:[{text:'hello'}]}]

const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())


app.post('/add',(res,req)=>{

const { text,id } = req.body
const user = Data.find(item => item.id === id)
user.messeges.push({text})
res.send('Done !')

})

app.listen(3001)
```

When I take a log from req.body  in app.post , it shows me undefined

Comment: In the client side, where are you defining the variable ´Data´?

Comment: yep... my data is something like this ```const Data = {text : 'hello',id:1}``` Of course, I think this is an extra work. But I just wanted to make sure the information was sent correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request and response are the wrong way round. Should be

```
app.post('/add',(req,res)=>{ // not res, req

const { text,id } = req.body
const user = Data.find(item => item.id === id)
user.messeges.push({text})
res.send('Done !')

})
```